# How important are extracurricular activities as a Mathematics Major?

Tags: mathematics, extracurricular

So I'm about halfway through my Sophomore year of college at LSU and on my way to a major in Mathematics with about a 4.05 GPA so far. My main objective is to be a desirable candidate for a good grad program. It doesn't really have to be a super top-tier school, but I wouldn't like to do a grad program in Mathematics at a school like LSU; I would like it to be a higher tier than that. I understand that my GPA and internships/work experience in my field are the two most important things for my major. So far, I haven't done any extracurriculars at all during the semester and worked at a summer camp the summer after my Freshman year. I plan on doing a math-related internship this summer. So, how important are extracurriculars during the semester? I find myself not having as much free time as I'd like when school is in session, so I held off on them. Is it important that I do something such as a community service group (which would be my main extracurricular interest) in order to make myself more desirable as a grad candidate? Thanks

Comment: You might want to edit in paragraph breaks for readability and a USA country tag, if that is the correct country.

Answer (score 1):

In the US, and I suspect elsewhere, such things have little bearing on admissions to graduate school. People will look at your academic achievements, mostly, but not entirely, in your major subject. They are looking for evidence of academic success and want to be able to make an easy prediction about your fit into their program. It is a much more important thing for admission to an undergraduate program in the US, but not a graduate program.

However, evidence of hard work and dedication to a goal can also be evidence of academic success. But the more important thing is the courses you took, your grades, and any writing you have done.

Comment: May I ask if you would think that doing 1 single extracurricular would make much of a difference? I get that doing many would be pointless, but if they see that I have literally zero extracurriculars, does that reflect negatively on me as a candidate? Thanks

Comment: Zero extracurricular activities won't affect grad school admission. No one will think of it.

Answer (score 1):

Not much.  They are looking for capabilities versus accomplishments.

I would also add that GREs are useful.